# Upload files to FTP server from Node js

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am trying to upload files to our FTP server. Its working fine when only one user is uploading the files. But the issue occurs when there are concurrent requests from different users to upload the files. I am getting connection failed error at that time and sometimes the error is Only 2 connections are allowed.  Here is my code

```
        try {
            const ftp = await configureFtpClient();
            if (!ftp) {
                console.log("Error while connecting ftp");
                return res.status(500).json({ error: ErrorMessage.FTP_SERVICE_MESSAGE });
            }
            const { files } = req.body;
            console.log("files_from_chat_service", files);
            const uploadPromises = files.map(file => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const uniqueFileName = Date.now() + '-' + path.basename(file.originalname);
                    const dataArray = file.buffer.data;
                    const buffer = Buffer.from(dataArray);
                    const tempFilePath = `uploads/${uniqueFileName}`;
                    fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, buffer);
                    const remoteFilePath = `uploads/${uniqueFileName}`;

                    ftp.on("ready", () => {
                        ftp.put(tempFilePath, remoteFilePath, (err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
                                fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (unlinkErr) => {
                                    if (unlinkErr) {
                                        console.error("Error deleting temp file:", unlinkErr);
                                    }
                                });
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("File uploaded successfully");
                                fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (unlinkErr) => {
                                    if (unlinkErr) {
                                        console.error("Error deleting temp file:", unlinkErr);
                                    }
                                });
                                resolve({ url: `${remoteFilePath}` });
                            }
                            ftp.end();
                        });
                    });

                    ftp.on("error", (err) => {
                        console.error("Error in ftp******", err.message);
                        fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (unlinkErr) => {
                            if (unlinkErr) {
                                console.error("Error deleting temp file:", unlinkErr);
                            }
                        });
                        reject(err);
                    });
                });
            });

            const response = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

            return res.status(200).json(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error message::::", err.message);
            return res.status(ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST).json({ error: err.message });
        }
    }
```

How can I make it enable to upload multiple files from different users at one time.